# Access Apex Map in Visualforce Javascript Method

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a map in apex class as a getter setter and currently accessing in the javascript of the visualforce page. But when i try to traverse a map, it is not displaying the values correctly, instead of each word, it is displaying the letters. Any help?
Code :

```
function test() {
  //This is how the map stored in apex controller
  var buttonMap = {apple=1,banana=2,Grapes=4}; 
  for(var key in buttonMap) {
     console.log(buttonMap[key]); //Which displays values as a p p l e b = 1 b a 
  }

}
```

Comment: How did button map get in such a state? That's not even legal JavaScript code.

Comment: Actually apex class returning the map in that format. I have below map in apex controller
for(LiveChatButton chatButton:[SELECT DeveloperName FROM LiveChatButton WHERE 
                    DeveloperName =:buttonNamesSet LIMIT :Limits.getLimitQueryRows() - Limits.getQueryRows()] ) {
                    buttonNameMap.put(chatButton.DeveloperName,chatButton.Id);
                }

And i am trying to access the map in the javascript as below
  var buttonIds = {};
   buttonIds = '{!buttonNameMap}';

Comment: when i did console.log for buttonIds map was below format (Removed actual ids and data for security purpose but it will be button name,buttonid)
{a=buttonId1, b=buttonid2, C=buttonId3}

Comment: can you share your apex controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apex Code's default serialization won't work for JavaScript. You need to convert it to JSON:

```
public String getButtonNameMap() {
  Map<String, Id> buttonNameMap = new Map<String, Id>();
  for(LiveChatButton chatButton:[SELECT DeveloperName FROM LiveChatButton WHERE DeveloperName =:buttonNamesSet LIMIT :Limits.getLimitQueryRows() - Limits.getQueryRows()] ) {
    buttonNameMap.put(chatButton.DeveloperName,chatButton.Id); 
   }
   return JSON.serialize(buttonNameMap);
}
```

And change your Visualforce slightly:

```
var buttonIds = {!buttonNameMap};
```

Comment: now the button map is somewhat OK It is rendering as ["buttonName":"buttonId","buttonName2":"buttonId2"]. But when try to loop through this map 
for(var key in buttonId) {
     console.log(buttonId[key]);
}
This is giving me same result , something like this [ b u t t o n 1

Comment: Finally i made it work @sfdcfox. I followed below link and it is working now. Thanks for your help.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69871/access-apex-map-in-javascript